# Get keys from json in python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have an API whose response is json like this:

```
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":[
     {
     "d":4,
     "e":5,
     "f":{
         "g":6
         }
     }
    ]
}
```

How can I write a python program which will give me the keys `['d','e','g']`. What I tried is:

```
jsonData = request.json() #request is having all the response which i got from api
c = jsonData['c']
for i in c.keys():
    key = key + str(i)
print(key)
```

Comment: "c" is a list. Try c[0].keys()

Comment: Do you need `['d','e','g']` or  `['d','e','f']` keys?

Comment: name of the keys.. ['d','e','g'] not values of ['d','e','g']

Comment: sorry, there are typo in comment. I have updated comment above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function which return only keys which aren't containing dictionary as their value.

```
jsonData = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": [{
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5,
        "f": {
            "g": 6
        }
    }]
}


def get_simple_keys(data):
    result = []
    for key in data.keys():
        if type(data[key]) != dict:
            result.append(key)
        else:
            result += get_simple_keys(data[key])
    return result

print get_simple_keys(jsonData['c'][0])
```

To avoid using recursion change line `result += get_simple_keys(data[key])`to `result += data[key].keys()`

Comment: Thanks andriy.. 
It gave me `['e', 'd', 'f']`. i want 'g' rather than 'f'. 
I think i need one more loop inside it.

Comment: yes but it wouldn't be best way ... need solution without recursion ?

Comment: yes please that would be very helpful. Thanks again @Andriy for your effort.

Comment: why this is fetching in the order `['e','d','g']` rather than `['d','e','g']`.. its ok but just out of curiosity.

Comment: Python dictionaries are actually are hash tables. Among other things, that means the order of the keys isn't guaranteed or even specified. If you need to get them sorted use `sorted(data.keys())` before iterating them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dct = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":[
         {
         "d":4,
         "e":5,
         "f":{
             "g":6
             }
         }
        ]
    }
k=dct["c"][0]
for key in k.keys(): 
    print key
```